# Парсинг xml Python

Tags: python, lxml

Есть файл xml, который нужно парсить на python, для нахождения тегов. Подскажите, как посчитать количество повторений этих тегов? Вывести в самом конце сам тег - количество.
Вот файл xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
        <book id="bk101">
            <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
            <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
            <genre>Computer</genre>
            <price>44.95</price>
            <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
            <description>An in-depth look at creating applications
            with XML.</description>
        </book>
        <book id="bk102">
            <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
            <title>Midnight Rain</title>
            <genre>Fantasy</genre>
            <price>5.95</price>
            <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
            <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies,
            an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen
            of the world.</description>
        </book>
        <book id="bk103">
            <author>Corets, Eva</author>
            <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
            <genre>Fantasy</genre>
            <price>5.95</price>
            <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
            <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology
            society in England, the young survivors lay the
            foundation for a new society.</description>
        </book>
</catalog>
```

Ниже код:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from lxml import etree


def parseBookXML(xmlFile):
    with open(xmlFile) as fobj:
        xml = fobj.read()

    root = etree.fromstring(xml)

    book_dict = {}
    books = []
    for book in root.getchildren():
        for elem in book.getchildren():
            if not elem.text:
                text = "None"
            else:
                text = elem.text
            print(elem.tag + " => " + text)
            book_dict[elem.tag] = text

        if book.tag == "book":
            books.append(book_dict)
            book_dict = {}

    return books


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parseBookXML("books.xml")
```

Answer (score 2):

Интересненько. Формализую задачу: вам нужно найти количество повторений тегов. Непонятно каких...
Например для всех:

```py
import re
from collections import Counter

def parseBookXML(xmlFile):
    with open(xmlFile) as fobj:
        xml = fobj.read()

    # понимаю, что все тэги парные и смысла включать все нет смысла,
    # буду забирать только открывающиеся
    pattern = r"<\w{1,}" 
    
    how_many_tags = Counter(re.findall(pattern, k))
    
    # что содержит how_many_tags
    # Counter({'<book': 3, '<author': 3, '<title': 3, '<genre': 3, '<price': 3, '<publish_date': 3, '<description': 3, '<catalog': 1})

    # если напрягают символы в начале ключей, то можно почистить
    clear = {}
    for i in how_many_tags:
        key = i[1:]
        clear[key] = how_many_tags[i]
    
    # ну, и переменная clear {'catalog': 1, 'book': 3, 'author': 3, 'title': 3, 'genre': 3, 'price': 3, 'publish_date': 3, 'description': 3}
```

Если нужен подсчет вместе с закрывающими, то умножьте на 2 все значения и будет вам счастье.